# husky pre-commit hook not triggering

Tags: git, husky

I am having an issue with `husky`. I would like for husky to run `eslint` and prettier at the point at which git commit is about to be done so that it can enforce clean coding checks. I have already setup `eslint`, `prettier` and integrated both. They are working fine when used manually. However, husky allows a commit if one of the `eslint` rules is violated.

I also renamed the `pre-commit.sample` file in my local project's `.git/hooks` directory to `pre-commit`.

This is my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc 'src/**/*.ts' 'test/**/*.ts' --write",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run prettier-format && npm run lint"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^7.0.1"
  }
```

Please, what could be the problem here?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an easier way to do this without having to initiate the installation of husky by myself.

I installed lint-staged and tested husky pre-commit hooks that was setup by it by running the following commands:

```
npx mrm@2 lint-staged
yarn install
```

The first line installs lint-staged and husky and adds the right sections with a sample script in the target package.json file for you to use or modify.

Stage and commit the target package.json into git (local git is enough). Make a change that should cause the eslint find errors and the commit to fail. Try committing again to test the lint-staged setup.
Lint-staged should prevent the files from being committed this time around.

Answer (score 7):

I think for this to work with `husky` v7, you need to move what you want to run pre-commit into a file called `.husky/pre-commit`. `husky` v7 won't use the configuration from your `package.json`. See [here for upgrading from v4 to v7](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=migrate-from-v4-to-v7).

Comment: Hello, I will check this out and let you know the results. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much @Rin for your answer. However, a lot changed and I did not complete the setup of husky for that project before moving on to something else. Recently, I had to work on a Javascript project where I did the project setup and had to do this again. I found another way that I consider easier that did not require adding the commands that I wanted to run in the `.husky/pre-commit`. I used lint-staged. I will describe this approach in detail below. :)